# jest.restoreAllMocks and mockFn.mockReset does not restore my unmocked function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am learning jest trying to understand how `mockClear()`, `mockReset()` and `mockRestore()` works. I wrote the below code in my `calc.test.js` file.

```
import {add} from "./calc";

jest.mock("./calc", () => {
  return {
    add: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe("testing calculator functions", () => {
  test("mocking add function and testing", () => {
    add.mockImplementation((a, b) => a * b);
    expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(2);
  });

  test("testing add without mocking", () => {
    add.mockRestore();
    expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

The first test passes as expected. But my second test fails. The error I get is :

```
Expected: 3
Received: undefined
```

I also replaced `add.mockRestore();` with  `jest.restoreAllMocks();` in the second test case but I get the same error.

I also tried moving `add.mockRestore();` inside my first test case. It produced the same error.

My understanding is that `mockFn.mockRestore()` restores the original (non-mocked) implementation. Hence `add(1,2)` should be 3 in my second test case. Had I used `mockReset()` in the place of `mockRestore()`, `undefined` should be the output, but why do I get `undefined` when I use `mockRestore()`?

The below code works fine. Both the test cases pass, but there is no requirement to use `mockRestore()` in this scenario. How do I use `mockRestore()` when mocking?

```
describe("testing calculator functions", () => {
  test("mocking add function and testing", () => {
    const mockAdd = jest.fn().mockImplementation((a, b) => a * b);
    expect(mockAdd(1, 2)).toBe(2);
  });

  test("testing add without mocking", () => {
    expect(calc.add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is your `add` function is imported as a mocked version due to `jest.mock()` being called at the top level, and the ***original implementation is never imported.***

So as fix you will need to modify your code to import the original implementation of the add function and use ***[`jest.spyOn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)*** to mock it. Using it, you keep a reference to the original implementation of add and can restore it later. Something like(the code is not tested but you get the idea):

```js
import * as calc from "./calc";

const addSpy = jest.spyOn(calc, 'add');

describe("testing calculator functions", () => {
  test("mocking add function and testing", () => {
    addSpy.mockImplementation((a, b) => a * b);
    expect(calc.add(1, 2)).toBe(2);
    addSpy.mockClear(); // <-- Clear the mock to ensure it doesn't affect other tests
  });

  test("testing add without mocking", () => {
    addSpy.mockRestore(); // <--- Restore to the original implementation
    expect(calc.add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

##### EDIT:

As per your comment, since you want to use only `jest.mock`, then one way which I can think of is to play around with ***[`jest.requireOriginal()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename)***.

```js
import { add as mockedAdd } from "./calc";
const { add: actualAdd } = jest.requireActual("./calc");
jest.mock("./calc", () => {
  return {
    add: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe("testing calculator functions", () => {
  test("mocking add function and testing", () => {
    mockedAdd.mockImplementation((a, b) => a * b);
    expect(mockedAdd(1, 2)).toBe(2);
    mockedAdd.mockClear();
  });

  test("testing add without mocking", () => {
    mockedAdd.mockImplementation(actualAdd); <-- Notice this
    expect(mockedAdd(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

And to answer the latest question that you added in your edit, No! `mockFn.mockRestore` only works for a mock function created with `jest.spyOn`.

***[Reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore)***

Comment: Thanks, but I only want to use jest.mock(). How do I restore my mock to my original method, without using spyOn? I tried to import `import * as calc from "./calc";` and used `calc.add(1, 2)` while using mock. It did not work too.

Comment: I tried to import `import * as calc from "./calc";` and used `calc.add(1, 2)` while calling add. It did not work too.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the update, it works. But the issue is that even if you comment out the  `mockedAdd.mockClear();` in the first test case, still it works. I want to use `mockRestore()` with jest.mock. I am trying to understand how mockRestore() works. I have also updated my question with an updated piece of code.

Comment: @GauthamMuralidharan, See the last line of my post. I have added the answer to your doubt that we can use `mockRestore` only with `jest.spyOn` along with reference.